# garbage collection - null reference and referencing new object

Tags: java, scjp

I would like to understand when the object created  in line-1 will be garbage collection...I assume its on line3 but I dont see that as an option in my answer- Line 4 & 5 is part of the answer

```
class MyObject{
    public void myMethod(){
        System.out.println("Mymethod");
    }
}


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObject m = new MyObject(); //line1
        m.myMethod();//line2
        m = null;//line3
        m = new MyObject();//line4
        m.myMethod();//line5
    }

}
```

Comment: you're right. Answer should be Line 3.

Comment: Note: is is eligible for GC after line 3, so perhaps line 4 is the answer.  It might not ever be cleaned up.

Comment: References can be ready for garbage collection, but there's no way to say when exactly this is.

Comment: It's eligible to be collected after the assignment to null. After that there are no live references to it. Whether it actually is collected then is implementation defined.

Comment: All of these answers that say that after line 3 is when it becomes eligible for collection, which is the best answer we can know, do all assume that myMethod doesn't cause a reference to m to be stored somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

If you set a reference to null that does not mean that garbage collector will kick in and will clean the memory for it.

Only eligible/marked Objects are garbage collected when JVM Garbage Collector kicks in. Garbage collector checks all the objects which are eligible for garbage collection i.e objects that are not referenced from anywhere.

JVM uses a process called Marking to mark the objects for garbage collection. And when GB kicks in it will simply delete the marked objects.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is that it is not possible to say when the object created at line 1 will be garbage collected.  All you can say definitely is that it becomes *eligible* to be garbage collected at line 3.  It *could* be garbage collected after line 3, but we cannot say that it *will* be.